# error during Switching inside the frameset?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

HTML CODE

```
<html style="width:100%; height:100%" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<frameset id="mainframeset" tabindex="-1" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize="" rows="1*">
</html>
```

inside the frame set there is another HTML Head and body where in which i cant able to access through selenium webdriver . some how i need to switch the control to inside the frame set so that i can get the web page control . How to get the access

The Selenium Code which i have written is

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// Enter URL to Address Bar
WebElement mainframe = driver.findElement(By.id("mainframeset"));
driver.get(baseUrl);
// Get the Title of the page
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
// Print Title in Console 
System.out.println("Title: "+actualTitle);
driver.switchTo().frame(mainframe);
```

Comment: what you are passing as (mainframe) ?? Also are you trying to access parent frame or sub frame?

Comment: Please add the html code snippet of the **frame** you need to switch to. I mean with tag **<frame>** or **<iframe>**, because you need to switch to a certain frame, and not a frameset.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to other frame in below manner. In your case I assume you want to switch to frame with id    '**mainframeset**'

```
WebDriverWait  frame_Test = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
frame_Test.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("mainframeset")));
```

Perform all the required operations inside the frame and to switch back to your default frame use below code.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```